# Simulate observable time passage in Angular 4 tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, rxjs5

I'm trying to write unit tests for component that uses observable data services. I have a problem with data service, which makes a HTTP call and can return data with a delay.

I mocked the service to return an observable of a subject. Then in 'it' blocks I push what I need down that stream (errors, correct data etc). In this case however I cannot simulate passage of time - the application is never in a loading state, since data service responds immediatly. So I added delay operator to the mock. Advancing the time using tick() doesn't seem to work correctly with the delay operator however.

I tried it in other way: for the mock I used TestScheduler. Then I advance time using flush(). However the problem with flush is that it advances the time to the end of the stream (I can't do step by step). I can't change the emitted values by per-test basis as well, since the observable is hardcoded. I would need to configure the TestBed again with a different mock provider if I want a different observable.

Did anyone have some success testing observables in this manner?

EDIT:

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
1. I create service mock and inject it as a provider for my component.

2a. I make the mock service return a ColdObservable using TestScheduler.
e.g. stream = TestScheduler.createColdObservable('-a', {a: myData})

it('should show loading status, () => {
    expect(component.loading).toBe(true);
    flush();
    expect(component.loading).toBe(false);
});

2b. I make the mock service return a subject. Then I next the values I need 
for tests.

it('should handle errors, () => {
    stream.next(error);
    expect(component.errors.length).toBe(1);
});
```

In the first example, when I'm using TestScheduler, I can't next() any values. In the second example when I'm using subject I can't do flush() or handle time in any way (emissions happen instantly).

I'm looking for a way to have both:
1. I can change what's emitted on per-test basis.
2. I can simulate time passage.
Without the need to go through configuring the TestBed again with different provider.

Comment: Can you show some code what you're trying to achieve? I don't understand what's to problem with TestScheduler.